# when i open terminal is a blank screen. No directory names or $. So I can't execute any commands

Tags: 14.04, command-line, gnome-terminal, bashrc

installed Ubuntu 14.4.0 ll of a sudden all i'm getting when I open my terminal is a blank screen. No directory names or $. So I can't execute any commands to update, install, fix or anything. All the help out I come across assume I can use the command line. . Anyone knows how to fix this? or how maybe how I can recover the default bashrc file (without using the command line)? Is my only option uninstalling and reinstalling Ubuntu?

but when i open gnome-terminal from usr/bin then it works fine , 
plz help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu, there is a default version of the .bashrc file in the /etc/skel/ directory, so if you have problems with it you can restore it.

To do so follow the next steps:

**Backup your current .bashrc file:**

cp ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc.bak

**Copy the skeleton .bashrc file over yours:**

cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/

**Afterwards, load the new one:**

source ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 2):

try to use the following solutions (**THERE ARE 3 SOLUTIONS READ THEM ALL**)

**SOLUTION A ::**

open your terminal and then press Ctrl+c if some process is running then it will be terminated and you are free to use the terminal

**SOLUTION B ::**

if you are still having a problem then do the following steps::

**A**] Go to your file manager and press Ctrl+L and paste the following::
        /etc/skel/.bashrc

**B**] After the above step you must see a .bashrc file which you should copy and 
      paste it else where to create its backup

**c**] Now Just press CTRL+ALT+F1 & login there then paste as
      cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
      source .bashrc
      Then type CTRL+ALT+F7 to reverse to GUI desktop.

**SOLUTION C ::**

Now if all of the above solutions fail try the final solution

**A**]open the terminal

**B**]go to edit ->preferences->command

**C**]**UN-SELECT** the **Run a custom command instead of my shell.**

**D**]Close it and restart the terminal.

[IMAGE OF THE edit ->preferences->command SCREEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUKOE.png)